# Parsing Excel with Python Pandas 0.18 => 23,999 (European style) gets parsed as 23999

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm using Pandas 0.18 to parse an `.xlsx` file which has float columns with values having 2 or 3 digits 'below' zero. Somehow Pandas (running on Flask server, US-style) parses this as thousands.

```
df=pd.read_excel(filepath)
df['T'] = pd.to_numeric(df['T'] ,errors='coerce')
```

Values with only 2 digits (`23,99`) are converted to `23.99` which is ok.
Values with 3 digits (`23,999`) are converted to `23999`.

Is this a bug or did I miss options or should I change the setting on the Flask/Pandas server? (this might give troubles when uploading US style Excel sheets)

Comment: What format are the affected Excel cells using? Standard or Number or Text?